# Registry values in a different language

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I have an application that requires .Net. I have found out how to check registry values to see if .Net is installed and whether or not it is the proper version.

What I want to know is this: Will registry values change based on the Language setting of the OS. That is, if someone in Peru installs .Net and my application calls something like

```
key.GetValue("Version");
```

will "Version" be recognised? or will it need to be the Spanish form of "Version".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm 99.99% certain that it will always be "Version". There's no point in translating registry keys, and it would only make things harder for developers everywhere.

Having said that, it's obviously best to find a key which is documented by Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

The registry values will be the same.